# How to make a matrix (or variable) read-only in Octave?

Tags: variables, matrix, octave

I load the matrix from a CSV using `fgetl`, and want to make sure that it doesn't change.

How to make the matrix (or any variable) read-only after the values are set?

Comment: Variables won't change unless you change them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not use octave, but I see that it has classes now, if it is anything like In Matlab, i'd then use class property.

From matlab help:

```
"Immutable set access — only the class constructor can set property values.
You cannot change the value of an object property"
```

I do not know how much different Octave from Matlab, but I read they are not much different, so may be you can see if this works on Octave.

But if you are really worried about your data not changing by mistake, then you can just leave it on disk, and read it each time you want to *process* or look at it.

Unless it is huge data, this should not be an issue these days.